# How do I prove that a Skew-Normal or Skew-Logistic Distribution is a Distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**How do I prove that a Skew-Normal or Skew-Logistic Distribution is a Distribution?**

In the literature, I found that for $\phi(x)$ being Gaussian or Logistic or any other univariate distribution, and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \phi(x) dx$, we obtain again a distribution by

$p(x)=2\phi(x)\Phi(ax)$

for any real valued $a$.

Comment: You would want to show that $p(x)$ is non-negative (easy) and that $\int_{\mathbb R}p(x)\, dx = 1$.  For the latter, you might consider what you get from $\frac{d}{dx} (\Phi(ax))^2$ and then whether you need to correct your question (Did you mean to include $a$? If so, did you include it often enough?)

Comment: Yes, that a is the puzzle. Especially as it can be negative and is only in the second term!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems $\phi(x)\geq 0$ implies $\Phi(x)\geq 0$. Thus, positivity is given. We also need $\Phi(x)+\Phi(-x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) dx = 1$ and can show
$$
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2 \phi(x) \Phi(ax) dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 2\phi(x) \Phi(ax) dx + \int_{0}^\infty 2 \phi(x) \Phi(ax) dx\\
&= -\int_0^{\infty} 2\phi(-x) \Phi(-ax) dx + \int_{0}^\infty 2 \phi(x) \Phi(ax) dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} 2\phi(x) \Phi(-ax) dx + \int_{0}^\infty 2 \phi(x) \Phi(ax) dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} 2\phi(x) (\Phi(-ax) + \Phi(ax)) dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty} 2\phi(x) dx\\
&= 2\int_0^{\infty} \phi(x) dx\\
&=1  
\end{align}
$$